# How to use email instead of username in Symfony4 if I extend AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony4

I have `email` field in my `login.html.twig` and want to pass last entered `email`, not username, to my template. How can I get `email` form AuthenticationUtils::getLastUsername()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `email` to session inside `getCredentials()` method of your `LoginAuthenticator` class:

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('password')
    ];

    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['email']
    );

    return $credentials;
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure. Ask more